# Push deposit notification through HTTP requests

Tags: development

Is there any alternative to bitcoinnotify? That send a POST request to a URL on an deposit event to a chosen address.

I know there is blockchain.info that send email. And instawallet that where you keep a open socket connection. But I am looking specifically for one that sends a HTTP request.

Answer (score 6):

Bitping.net is the new service that replaces BitcoinNotify and can provide the service you are requesting.

Answer (score 5):

Blockchain.info now also supports HTTP Post. See https://blockchain.info/wallet/payment-notifications for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.bitcoinmonitor.net. Besides the common features it includes a notification history and status info for each individual callback. Also possible is notification via RSS/atom feed and of course email.
As a bonus everything can be set up using a RESTful API.